# How to prevent quitting vim accidentally?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to rebind :q in vim to a more complex command to prevent accidentally exiting vim?

Comment: :q isn't complex enough?  I never hit that accidentally myself...

Comment: I agree with @EricJ. You have to type `:`, then `q`, then press Enter. What common command that *doesn't* quit is close to that?

Comment: @KeithThompson - Well, `q:` is close to that, in a manner of speaking. I don't know how common it is though.

Comment: But the point is still well made. If you're accidentally hitting a three key combination, you're gonna have a hell of a time in vim, in which most things are done with one letter combination (two, if you're counting <esc>)

Comment: I've hit many things trying to type `:q`, but never the reverse.

Comment: @EricJ. The problem for me is in gVim, when quitting closes the window, rather than just dropping me back into my terminal window.

Comment: I like this question because one my workflows has one gvim window opened for numerous python files.  I can be open for weeks and I display it on all desktops (linux) so when it closes it is inconvenient to have to re-enable displaying it on all desktops, and the MRU file list seems to be lost.  The :q happens when I am working quickly and just accidentally type :q (which I do in terminal vi sessions all the time) but in gvim I meant to switch buffers.  There are probably workarounds but this question resonates with me.

Comment: Leda may, like me, have a habit of quitting and is trying to learn to quit exiting every time she's finished with an edit.  (Which is why I found this post).

Comment: For me, it is that I have a 20+ year habit in vi/vim - edit file, :q do something at command line.  So, :q is reflexive.

I want to break that habit.  When I've opened 15 buffers, :q is painful to recover from.

Comment: I have a habit of typing in the extra `q` when I just want to save with `:w`, so it ends up `:wq`. This is from years of using vim as a cmd only config file editor instead of a full blown editor.

Comment: This question makes sense as I use vim in different ways. For git commits in one shell, git fires up vim for me, I write a log message and then hits ":w" followed by ":q", which is a sequence of 6 keys trivial enough to write by reflex and for git commits that reflex is just fine!  However, for longer edits and code development, I have a vim with over 20 open files in another shell, and THAT vim I really want to remain running in spite of my reflex of typing ":w" ":q" when I'm done with one of my files. (...and there is a solution by user1655874 I found useful below!)

Answer (score 15):

What you want is `:close`. It acts like `:q` but won't let you close the last window:

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:close

You can set an alias for the `q` command to map to `close`:

```
cabbrev q <c-r>=(getcmdtype()==':' && getcmdpos()==1 ? 'close' : 'q')<CR>
```

Thanks @Paradoxial for this :cabbrev trick.

Comment: Added this, then closed vimrc with a quick `:wq`. Whoops.

Comment: There seems to be a bug in nvim 0.6 whereby it closes unsaved buffers on `:q`. I found this question because I have a 20-year habit of autonomously hitting `:w` while I work. After losing my left pinkie during a night of blow and loose women, the little stump now often hits `q` instead of `w`. Tragic corner-case...but funny.

Answer (score 11):

I know, I know, it is a very old question, but I had the same question today and I found this post first. I developed a short script to put in .vimrc

```
function! ConfirmQuit(writeFile)
    if (a:writeFile)
        if (expand('%:t')=="")
            echo "Can't save a file with no name."
            return
        endif
        :write
    endif

    if (winnr('$')==1 && tabpagenr('$')==1)
        if (confirm("Do you really want to quit?", "&Yes\n&No", 2)==1)
            :quit
        endif
    else
        :quit
    endif
endfu

cnoremap <silent> q<CR>  :call ConfirmQuit(0)<CR>
cnoremap <silent> x<CR>  :call ConfirmQuit(1)<CR>
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 5):

What are you afraid of? Vim won't let you quit (without a `!` command modifier, anyway) when you still have unsaved changes, so the only thing you'll potentially lose is the window position, size, and maybe taskbar position of GVIM.

Anyway, to override built-in commands like `:q`, you can use the [cmdalias plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=746), like this:

```
:Alias q if\ winnr('$')>1||tabpagenr('$')>1||confirm('Really\ quit?',\ "&OK\\n&Cancel")==1|quit|endif
```

This checks for the last window (`:q` does not necessarily exit Vim), and inserts a confirmation.

Comment: The problem is that `q` is awfully close to `!`.

Comment: @Qix: But you usually need Shift to get the `!`; neither `:q1` nor `:Q!` to any harm. If you're afflicted by fat-fingering, you won't have much fun in Vim, anyway.

Comment: I was being partially facetious. This was the first instance I've ever fat fingered `q!` in the few years I've been using Vim, lol.

Answer (score 5):

You can use something like this to remove the `:q` command:

```
:cabbrev q <c-r>=(getcmdtype()==':' && getcmdpos()==1 ? 'echo' : 'q')<CR>
```

This abbreviates `q` to `echo` in command mode, but doesn't allow the abbreviation to trigger if the `q` isn't in the first column. This way, `edit q` won't abbreviate to `edit echo`.

Comment: Wonderful solution! Forces me to write ":quit" in that particular vim I intend to keep around for months. For short lived vim sessions (like those for git commit messages) in another shell, ":q" still works as intended.

Answer (score 3):

ConfirmQuit.vim : Provides a confirm dialog when you try to quit vim

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1072

I adapted this by using

```
autocmd bufenter c:/intranet/notes.txt cnoremap <silent> wq<cr> call ConfirmQuit(1)<cr>
```

As I only wanted this on this for a particular file

Comment: Thank you!

However, anyone using plain vim that uses ConfirmQuit.vim will want to remove the "if has("gui_running")"

Answer (score 0):

Using the [coot/cmdalias_vim](https://github.com/coot/cmdalias_vim) plugin, I effectively disabled the short, impulsive quit commands `:q`, `:q!`, and `:wq`.  Hopefully this will slow me down and make me think about whether I really want to use `:quit` or, say, `:bdelete`.  Here's a condensed version of the "autocmd section" of my `.vimrc` file:

```
if has("autocmd")
    augroup VIMRC_aliases
        au!
        au VimEnter * CmdAlias wqu\%[it] write|quit
        au VimEnter * CmdAlias q         echo\ "Use\ :qu[it]\ instead\ of\ :q"
        au VimEnter * CmdAlias q!        echo\ "Use\ :qu[it]!\ instead\ of\ :q!"
        au VimEnter * CmdAlias wq        echo\ "Use\ :wqu[it]\ instead\ of\ :wq"
    augroup END
endif
```