# How to prevent quitting vim regardless of the reason it quits?

Tags: vim

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556267/how-to-prevent-quitting-vim-accidentally) question, but it doesn't answer the issue I have.

So I have F2 button mapped to save changes. Escape is for leaving insert mode. So to save changes I hit escape and then press F2 (usually several times - to make sure I really hit it :) ). And I can't even figure out how this happens, that I hit some button (probably Escape) at some moment, that it closes vim with all my open tabs and buffers, as everything is usually saved. This happened to me so many times, that I finally decided to post a question.

How to prevent exiting Vim, regadless of the way or reason (:q, triple Escape, etc) it's going to quit, so that I couldn't exit from it without confirmation?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you mean.

Comment: Hm. I just want vim to ask for confirmation every time it's going to quit, whenever I press :q, tripple escape or something else (if there is some key combination). Don't know how to express it in other words

Comment: first you have to make sure that your problem could be 100% reproduce, E.g. when I press `<ESC>` 3 times, vim quit.  not  `this happens, that I hit some button (probably Escape) at some moment, that it closes vim with all my open tabs and buffers, as everything is usually saved. This happened to me so many times`  anyway, check if there is mapping on `ESC` is useful, if you are sure the problem is  on `ESC` key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your case: It is strange that triple Escape quits VIM that is not standard behavior. Even :q would not quite all tabs. You can check what is mapped on your Escape:

```
:verbose map <Esc>
```

There must be something like `qa!`.

Comment: Exactly! <ESC><ESC><ESC> was mapped to qa! Somehow even <ESC><ESC>F2 worked like that. Thanks!